# Keep dependent windows (e.g. XML Schema Explorer) open

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

In VS 2010 (or later), is there a way to keep a dependent window (or whatever you call a window which is only open when a certain type of file is open) from closing when you change the active file? Is there a plugin perhaps?

I'm writing out properties from an XML schema in to a class, and having the XML schema explorer close every time I move to the code file is incredibly annoying, even though the schema designer is visible on the other screen (but not the active file).

Comment: Trying to do exactly the same thing, it's very annoying isn't it?  Had to open another visual studio instance with the schemas in.